# Query not inserting the data into db?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone tell me what i have done wrong here? It's driving me crazy!

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "admin_responsivecontact");


    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Error: Could not connect to database');
    }
    else {echo "success";}
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO contact (id,name,company,job,email,tel,info,guide,add,date) VALUES (1,'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'", "'.$_POST['name'].'")';


    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: post your error and for the love of god PLEASE DONT USE CODE LIKE THAT. adding POST arguments to your sql string will open you to sql injections. Alternative: Prepared Statements (https://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Wrong? Well, you check for connection errors but assume all queries will work. Not sure if you mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add` is a [`reserved word`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Enclose it in backticks !

You should do like

```
'INSERT INTO contact (`id`,`name`,`company`,`job`,`email`,`tel`,`info`,`guide`,`add`,`date`)
                                                                 //Like this          ^---^
```

Answer (score 0):

Many issues in the code above:

1) Easily injectable, no sanitizing performed.
2) Reuses the same POST variable instead of storing it in a worker variable which should then be sanitized.
3) Using MySQL keywords as field names without backticks.
4) Not escaping the input. So if somebody enters a name with apostrophe(s) errors will occur. Also related to 1).
5) You have a field called "id". They are usually autoincrementing so you can't just assign it "1" and be done with it. One solution is to just omit it and let MySQL fill in the proper current counter value.
6) Apparently you have a field called: "date" so it's possibly a typed field. Yet you seem to assign it the same string you assigned to the other fields.